# Pandas and Yahoo ChartAPI

Tags: api, python-3.x, pandas, urllib, yahoo-finance

I am trying to read from [this source - Yahoo Finance](http://chartapi.finance.yahoo.com/instrument/1.0/EURUSD=X/chartdata;type=quote;range=1y/csv) from line 17 onwards. I want to get the date, highprice, lowprice, etc, which are the 6 columns.

My code:

```
import pandas as pd 
import datetime
import urllib
web = 'http://chartapi.finance.yahoo.com/instrument/1.0/EURUSD=X/chartdata;type=quote;range=1y/csv'

urlToVisit = 'http://chartapi.finance.yahoo.com/instrument/1.0/EURUSD=X/chartdata;type=quote;range=1y/csv'
with urllib.request.urlopen(urlToVisit) as response:
    sourcePage = response.read().decode()
df = pd.read_csv(sourcePage, skiprows=17, header=None)
df.head()
```

---

```
    OSError                                   Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-10-bf04141dec86> in <module>()
      7 with urllib.request.urlopen(urlToVisit) as response:
      8     sourcePage = response.read().decode()
----> 9 df = pd.read_csv(sourcePage, skiprows=17, header=None)
     10 df.head()

/opt/conda/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py in parser_f(filepath_or_buffer, sep, dialect, compression, doublequote, escapechar, quotechar, quoting, skipinitialspace, lineterminator, header, index_col, names, prefix, skiprows, skipfooter, skip_footer, na_values, true_values, false_values, delimiter, converters, dtype, usecols, engine, delim_whitespace, as_recarray, na_filter, compact_ints, use_unsigned, low_memory, buffer_lines, warn_bad_lines, error_bad_lines, keep_default_na, thousands, comment, decimal, parse_dates, keep_date_col, dayfirst, date_parser, memory_map, float_precision, nrows, iterator, chunksize, verbose, encoding, squeeze, mangle_dupe_cols, tupleize_cols, infer_datetime_format, skip_blank_lines)
    496                     skip_blank_lines=skip_blank_lines)
    497 
--> 498         return _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)
    499 
    500     parser_f.__name__ = name

/opt/conda/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py in _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)
    273 
    274     # Create the parser.
--> 275     parser = TextFileReader(filepath_or_buffer, **kwds)
    276 
    277     if (nrows is not None) and (chunksize is not None):

/opt/conda/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py in __init__(self, f, engine, **kwds)
    588             self.options['has_index_names'] = kwds['has_index_names']
    589 
--> 590         self._make_engine(self.engine)
    591 
    592     def _get_options_with_defaults(self, engine):

/opt/conda/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py in _make_engine(self, engine)
    729     def _make_engine(self, engine='c'):
    730         if engine == 'c':
--> 731             self._engine = CParserWrapper(self.f, **self.options)
    732         else:
    733             if engine == 'python':

/opt/conda/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py in __init__(self, src, **kwds)
   1101         kwds['allow_leading_cols'] = self.index_col is not False
   1102 
-> 1103         self._reader = _parser.TextReader(src, **kwds)
   1104 
   1105         # XXX

pandas/parser.pyx in pandas.parser.TextReader.__cinit__ (pandas/parser.c:3246)()

pandas/parser.pyx in pandas.parser.TextReader._setup_parser_source (pandas/parser.c:6111)()
```

Would greatly appreciate if someone could help me rectify! Thank you.

Comment: I think the method here is an easier way:  http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/remote_data.html

Comment: @JohnE Thanks for your suggestion. However, I don't think that works for FOREX?

Comment: oh sorry, I'm not sure.  thought you were just grabbing stock data.

Comment: I got the method here to work, but it just has one price per day.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21483959/how-can-get-usdjpycurrency-rates-with-pandas-and-yahoo-finance  I did this:  `web.DataReader('DEXUSEU', 'fred')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the document, [`pandas.read_csv`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/io.html#io-read-csv-table) need a file-like object as the first parameter.

So you can either save the file locally and re-read it using `pandas.read_csv` method, or you can use [`io.StringIO`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.StringIO) in Python 3.x or [`StringIO.StringIO`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stringio.html#StringIO.StringIO) in Python 2.x to convert the data.

Here is sample code:

```
import io
import urllib
import urllib.request
import pandas as pd

urlToVisit = 'http://chartapi.finance.yahoo.com/instrument/1.0/EURUSD=X/chartdata;type=quote;range=1y/csv'
with urllib.request.urlopen(urlToVisit) as response:
    sourcePage = response.read().decode()

df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(sourcePage), skiprows=18, header=None, sep=",")
print(df.head())
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Hey Eric, thank you. However, I still am encountering the same message.

Comment: Hi @misheekoh, can you update the error message? The format of error message is hard to recognize the problem

Comment: Hey @misheekoh I update my answer and you can check if it works for you or not.

Comment: hey, thank you. btw, would you know why it's only printing 5 rows?

Comment: The default parameter of [`dataframe.head()`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.head.html) is **5**, so it will only print 5 rows of data

Comment: Eh, I got it! Thanks!!