# why doesnt the below code work for stock option on yahoo finance

Tags: python, html, pandas

this code does not work for yahoo finance of google finance
works for 'http://www.bloomberg.com/markets/currencies/cross-rates'

```
import pandas as pd
from lxml.html import parse
from urllib2 import urlopen
from pandas.io.parsers import TextParser

def _unpack(row, kind='td'):
   elts = row.findall('.//%s' % kind)
   return [val.text_content() for val in elts]

def parse_options_data(table):
   rows = table.findall('.//tr')
   header = _unpack(rows[0], kind='th')
   data = [_unpack(r) for r in rows[1:]]
   return TextParser(data, names=header).get_chunk()
parsed = parse(urlopen('https://www.google.com/finance/option_chain?q=AAPL&ouput'))

doc = parsed.getroot()
tables = doc.findall('.//table')
table = parse_options_data(tables[1])
table
```

how do i fix?

Comment: you didn't import yahoo finance?

Comment: did you check already [pandas_datareader](http://pandas-datareader.readthedocs.io/en/latest/remote_data.html)?

Comment: No easy answer but a few pointers: The URL above is FX rates, not stock options. The code you've pasted just finds a table and parses out its entries. Yahoo / Google don't appear to have a page with the same format so it doesn't work. Try here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21483959/how-can-get-usdjpycurrency-rates-with-pandas-and-yahoo-finance

Comment: hi thesonyman101, thanks for your comment. I meant the codes dont work for either yahoo finance or google finance. In my code, I had 'https://www.google.com/finance/option_chain?q=AAPL&ouput'. if I put 'http://finance.yahoo.com/quote/AAPL/options?p=AAPL', it still doesnt work.

Comment: hi MaxU, thanks for the comments. Yes pandas_datareader works. However, for studying purpose, I'd want to learn how to use lxml.html and urllib2 as well.